# How to display numbers that are greater than a certain value?

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to set it up to only display only the numbers that are greater than 21 but I am struggling.

Here is the code I have so far.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   const int NUM_ELEMENTS = 8; // Number of elements
   int userVals[NUM_ELEMENTS]; // User numbers
   int i = 0;                  // Loop index

   // Prompt user to populate array
   cout << "Enter " << NUM_ELEMENTS << " integer values..." << endl;

   for (i = 0; i <= NUM_ELEMENTS; ++i) {
      cout << "Value: " << endl;
      cin >> userVals[i];
   }

   for (i = 0; i < NUM_ELEMENTS; ++i) {
      cout << userVals[i] << " ";
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's your problem? Could you explain in what way you are struggling?

Comment: Looping around and using arrays without knowing IF? I think You should learn a little bit and try to solve simpler problems before You start to work with others codes

Comment: one observation, make sure you only read in NUM_ELEMENTS, you have to replace the first for loop code"for (i = 0; i <= NUM_ELEMENTS; ++i)" with "for (i = 0; i < NUM_ELEMENTS; ++i)", just to make sure the index is not out of bounds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (i = 0; i < NUM_ELEMENTS; ++i)
{
  if(userVals[i] > 21)
    cout << userVals[i] << " ";
}
```

Comment: How is your answer helpful? Can you explain your code a bit?

Comment: In the loop it will check the value at userVals[i] (starting from 0, going to NUM_ELEMENTS). 

If the value userVals[i] is greater than 21, it will print out the value.

Comment: @user3816764 Well, yes, that's exactly what the code says. But why does it solve the OP's problem? What was the OP doing wrong? This doesn't show anything besides the code, and is thus unlikely to help them outside of this specific instance.

Comment: It seems really self evident to me.